# How can I prevent Supertab to try completion even if I just want to enter a tab?

Tags: vim, plugins, tab-completion

Even when I have an empty buffer in vim, supertab tries to do a completion at the begining. How can I configure supertab to only try tab-completion if there's a character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supertab triggers insert-mode completion only when there is non-whitespace text before the cursor. Behind whitespace, or at the beginning of a line, a `<Tab>` character should be inserted. Something's wrong with your setup.

Note that you can always insert a literal `<Tab>` with `<C-v><Tab>` (on Windows, you may have to use `<C-q>`).

Comment: Any ideas what could cause this problem?

Comment: A new git checkout solved the problem.

Comment: Ah, great you've solved it! So it was likely script corruption?! I couldn't think of any reason, sorry.

Comment: I have no clue. I can't remember changing anything in the git module. however pulling did nothing but removing the module and checking out a fresh copy helped. :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I have used the old version of snipmate (the version maintained by msanders). When I updated to [this version maintained by garbas and others](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) the problem has gone.

(I have tried to remove supertab and clone again. This alone had not fixed the problem.)

Comment: This answer led me to the [snipmate fork FAQ](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab/#frequently-asked-questions).  I didn't need to re-clone supertab, but an old snipmate was my problem too.